# Can't read csv from S3 to pyspark dataframe on a EC2 instance on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I can't read in a csv file from S3 to a pyspark dataframe on EC2 instance on AWS cloud.
I have created a spark cluster on AWS using Flintrock.
Here is my Flintrock configuration file (on a local machine):

```
services:
  spark:
    version: 3.0.0
  hdfs:
    version: 2.7.3

provider: ec2

providers:
  ec2:
    key-name: xxxx
    identity-file: /home/yyyy/keys/xxxx.pem
    instance-type: t2.micro
    region: us-east-1
    ami: ami-02354e95b39ca8dec
    user: ec2-user

launch:
  num-slaves: 1
  install-hdfs: False
```

Then I start the cluster on AWS as follows:

```
flintrock launch mysparkcluster
```

The cluster gets created and seems to work.
Then I install python3 as follows:

```
flintrock run-command mysparkcluster 'sudo yum install -y python3'
```

Then I login to the master node:

```
flintrock login mysparkcluster
```

Then I do:

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

Then I start the pyspark shell (so far it works!):

```
pyspark --master spark://0.0.0.0:7077 --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.4
```

Below in the pyspark shell I set the required credentials. Since I am using aws educate account, my understanding is that I get only always temporary sessions, for which I need session token in addition to access-key-id and secret key:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)

spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "KEYXYZ")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "SECRETXYZ")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.session.token", "VERYLONGTOKEN")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")
```

And then I try to read in the csv file as follows:

```
df = sqlc.read.csv('s3a://mybucket/myfile.csv', header='true', inferSchema='true')
```

I am getting the follwoing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 535, in csv
    return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/home/ec2-user/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/home/ec2-user/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 131, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/ec2-user/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o51.csv.
: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: EEAD03F2F4012750, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: mi9O78oh2QbtklTCrCQkv6SuPFR0UR6zl5CB4kuHTCJD7mdNrA6s5R8oejWJ0MAlAS8zOPJY7FY=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:421)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:976)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:956)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.isDirectory(FileSystem.java:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:268)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:705)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for you tips in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something with the way I supplied my credentials via hadoopConfiguration().set() in the python code was wrong. But there is another way of configuring flintrock (and more generally EC2 instances) to be able to access S3 without supplying credentials in the code (this is actually a recomded way of doing this when dealing with temporary credentials from AWS). The following helped:

- The [flintrock docu](https://github.com/nchammas/flintrock), which says "Setup an IAM Role that grants
  access to S3 as desired. Reference this role when you launch your
  cluster using the --ec2-instance-profile-name option (or its
  equivalent in your config.yaml file)."
- [This AWS documentation
  page](https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket/) that explains step-by-step how to do it.
- [Another useful AWS docu page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html).
- Please note: If you create the above role via AWS
  Console then the respective instance profile with the same name is
  created automatically, otherwise (if you use awscli or AWS API) you
  have to create the desired instance profile manually as an extra
  step.